# Content in div overlapping

Tags: html, css

I have a h3 tag and p tag in a div and they keep overlapping even though I've added margin.

```css
.title {
  margin: 0 0 26px;
  width: 335px;
  height: 28px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 36px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.para {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.75;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: #3f4658;
  margin: 26px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="new">
  <h3 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quae in controversiam veniunt, de iis, si placet, disseramus. Aliud </h3>

  <p class="para">
    Et si turpitudinem fugimus in statu et motu corporis, quid est cur pulchritudinem non sequamur? Hoc etsi multimodis reprehendi potest, tamen accipio, quod dant. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Quid me istud rogas? Varietates autem iniurasque fortunae
    facile veteres philosophorum praeceptis instituta vita superabat. Est enim effectrix multarum et magnarum voluptatum. Quod si ita se habeat, non possit beatam praestare vitam sapientia. Satis est ad hoc responsum.
  </p>

</div>
```

I need a flexible title meaning if I add more in the title it should be reponsive and not overlap the paragragh below it

Comment: You have added `height: 28px`. So what else are you expecting?

Comment: with a fixed height that is smaller then the contents height you encoutnerign an overflow-issue. remove the fixed height -> problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the height

```
height: 28px;
```

```css
.title {
  margin: 0 0 26px;
  width: 335px;
  /* height: 28px;   // Height Remove to achieve the normal flow */
  font-size: 24px;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 36px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.para {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.75;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: #3f4658;
  margin: 26px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="new">
  <h3 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quae in controversiam veniunt, de iis, si placet, disseramus. Aliud </h3>

  <p class="para">
    Et si turpitudinem fugimus in statu et motu corporis, quid est cur pulchritudinem non sequamur? Hoc etsi multimodis reprehendi potest, tamen accipio, quod dant. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Quid me istud rogas? Varietates autem iniurasque fortunae
    facile veteres philosophorum praeceptis instituta vita superabat. Est enim effectrix multarum et magnarum voluptatum. Quod si ita se habeat, non possit beatam praestare vitam sapientia. Satis est ad hoc responsum.
  </p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you see in the snippet below, you having an overflow that occures. the red border is 28px high while the overflowing content is cut off:

```css
/* for demonstration of the issue */
.title {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}


.title {
  margin: 0 0 26px;
  width: 335px;
  height: 28px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 36px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.para {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.75;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: #3f4658;
  margin: 26px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="new">
  <h3 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quae in controversiam veniunt, de iis, si placet, disseramus. Aliud </h3>

  <p class="para">
    Et si turpitudinem fugimus in statu et motu corporis, quid est cur pulchritudinem non sequamur? Hoc etsi multimodis reprehendi potest, tamen accipio, quod dant. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Quid me istud rogas? Varietates autem iniurasque fortunae
    facile veteres philosophorum praeceptis instituta vita superabat. Est enim effectrix multarum et magnarum voluptatum. Quod si ita se habeat, non possit beatam praestare vitam sapientia. Satis est ad hoc responsum.
  </p>

</div>
```

In your sampel the content oevrflows and as such collided with the element that follows. Either add an overflow rule to the title or remove the fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.title {
  margin: 0 0 26px;
  width: 335px;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 36px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.para {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.75;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: #3f4658;
  margin: 26px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="new">
  <h3 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quae in controversiam veniunt, de iis, si placet, disseramus. Aliud </h3>

  <p class="para">
    Et si turpitudinem fugimus in statu et motu corporis, quid est cur pulchritudinem non sequamur? Hoc etsi multimodis reprehendi potest, tamen accipio, quod dant. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Quid me istud rogas? Varietates autem iniurasque fortunae
    facile veteres philosophorum praeceptis instituta vita superabat. Est enim effectrix multarum et magnarum voluptatum. Quod si ita se habeat, non possit beatam praestare vitam sapientia. Satis est ad hoc responsum.
  </p>

</div>
```

Comment: Please update height: 28px to height: auto.